# Не работает скрипт при перезагрузке скрипта каталога

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Срочно нужна помощь! Я на сайте собираюсь выполнить функцию при которой появляется один элемент при определенном времени суток

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var   day = new Date();
   var   hour = day.getHours();
 $(window).load(function() {
    if (hour >= 23 && hour < 11) {
       $('.t-store__card__mark:eq('0')').css('display' , 'block');
    };
});
</script>
```

Но когда я начинаю выбирать категории товаров скрипт с каталогом перезагружается и возвращает элемент в исходное состояние, то есть пропадает, а должен появляться с 23 до 11. Класс элемента, который указан в скрипте является частью каталога. Каким образом решить данную задачу, чтобы скрипт всегда был подгружен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо:
 1. Использовать не `$(window).load`, а `$(window).on('load', function(){...}`
Так как `load` подгружает файл, который указан, а `on('load'` проверяет загрузку документа.
 2. В функции `if (hour >= 23 && hour < 11) {` используйте `||`(или) вместо `&&`(и) Потому что в противном случае он должен будет удовлетворять обоим вариантам одновременно. И быть больше 23 и одновременно быть меньше 11, что не возможно.
3. В строке `$('.t-store__card__mark:eq('0')')` у Вас стоит лишнее экранирование.

```js
    var   day = new Date();
    var   hour = day.getHours();
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        if (hour >= 23 || hour < 11) {
            $('.t-store__card__mark:eq(0)').css('display' , 'block');
        }
    });
```

```css
    .t-store__card__mark{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t-store__card__mark">Время ночь</div>
```

Comment: Метод .load до третьей версии jQuery с функций в аргументе выполнял функцию при загрузке документа. Это уже потом они отказались от коротких методов и теперь всё через on делается.